# How to access Docker container app on local?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I have a simple Node.js/Express app:

```
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

It works fine when I start it like: node src/app.js

Now I'm trying to run it in a Docker container. Dockerfile is:

```
FROM node:8

WORKDIR /app
ADD src/. /app/src
ADD package.json package-lock.json /app/

RUN npm install

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "node", "src/app.js" ]
```

It starts fine: `docker run <my image>:`

```
Listening on port 3000
```

But now I cannot access it in my browser:
http://localhost:3000

```
This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.
```

Same happen if I try to run it within docker-compose:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  service1:
    image: xxxxxx
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - xxxxxxxx
  myapp:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - private
    ports:
      - 3000
    command:
      node src/app.js
```

Not sure if I deal right with ports in both docker files

Comment: If publishing ports did not help as other answers mentioned, and if you are on MacOS try: app.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!\`))

instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
services:
  myapp:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - private
    ports:
      - 3000:3000 ##THIS IS THE CHANGE, YOU NEED TO MAP MACHINE PORT TO CONTAINER
    command:
      node src/app.js
```

Answer (score 3):

When you work with docker you must define the host for your app as `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost`.

For your express application you can define the host on `app.listen` call.

Check the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.listen): 
**app.listen([port[, host[, backlog]]][, callback])**

Your express code should be updated to:

```
const port = 3000
const host = '0.0.0.0'

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, host, () => console.log(`Example app listening on ${port}!`))
```

It's also important publish docker ports:

- Running docker: `docker run -p 3000:3000 <my image>`
- Running docker-compose:

```
services:
  myapp:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - private
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    command:
      node src/app.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish ports

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 <my image>
```

`-p` - stands for publish