# unable to access docker container port from localhost when using docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a very basic node/express app with a dockerfile and a docker-compose file. When I run the docker container using

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 service:0.0.1 npm run dev
```

I can go to localhost:3000 and see my service. However, when I do:

```
docker-compose run server npm run dev
```

I can't see anything on localhost:3000, below are my files:

Dockerfile

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3000
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
    server:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        image: service:0.0.1
        environment:
            - LOGLEVEL=debug
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        container_name: "website_service__db"
        image: postgres
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=user
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=pass
            - POSTGRES_DB=website_service
```

also, everything is working fine from the terminal/docker side - no errors and services are running fine, i just cant access the node endpoints

Comment: not quite sure if your build command does the same as dev, but as far i can see that's difference between how you run your code

Comment: Can you include the main function of your Express application?  Have you looked at some similar questions like [How to access Docker container app on local?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56484240/how-to-access-docker-container-app-on-local), which have some setup guidance?

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr

```
docker-compose run --service-ports server npm run dev
// the part that changed is the new '--service-ports' argument
```

the issue was a missing docker-compose run argument `--service-ports`:

from [these docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/):

> The second difference is that the docker-compose run command ***does not create any of the ports specified in the service configuration***. This prevents port collisions with already-open ports. ***If you do want the service’s ports to be created and mapped to the host***, specify the --service-ports flag: